# Summarize certain data fields of apache CLF log file

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, scripting, apache-httpd

I want to grep some information from raw [*combined log format*](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/logs.html#combined) **apache** logs:

```
51.254.56.62 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:28 +0500] "GET /vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://networkconfig.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
51.254.56.62 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:28 +0500] "GET /jquery.fullPage.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://networkconfig.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
51.254.56.62 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:29 +0500] "GET /js/TweenLite.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://networkconfig.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
51.254.56.62 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:29 +0500] "GET /js/EasePack.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://networkconfig.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
51.254.56.62 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:29 +0500] "GET /js/rAF.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://networkconfig.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
51.254.56.62 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:29 +0500] "GET /js/networkconfig.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://networkconfig.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
182.180.10.40 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:29 +0500] "GET /js/rAF.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://networkconfig.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
182.180.10.40 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:29 +0500] "GET /js/networkconfig.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://networkconfig.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
182.180.10.40 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:28 +0500] "GET /vendors/jquery.slimscroll.min.js HTTP/1.1" 404 - "http://networkconfig.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
182.180.10.40 - - [01/Jun/2016:20:49:28 +0500] "GET /jquery.fullPage.js HTTP/1.1" 304 - "http://networkconfig.net/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0"
```

This is what I have done:

```
  awk '{ print $1,$11}' accesslog | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head -n 10

  3 51.254.56.62 "http://networkconfig.net/"
  3 51.254.56.62 "http://networkconfig.com/"
  2 182.180.10.40 "http://networkconfig.net/"
  2 182.180.10.40 "http://networkconfig.com/"
```

What I want to get is:

```
Domains                     Hits By IP

networkconfig.net           3 hits 51.254.56.62  | 2 hits 182.180.10.40 and so on
networkconfig.com           3 hits 51.254.56.62 | 2 hits 182.180.10.40 and so on
```

Comment: Please specify the name of the program that made the log file.

Comment: actually these are apache webserver domlogs.

Answer (score 0):

*Revised version* (3nd) of *ugly.sh*:

```
#!/bin/bash
{ echo "Domains  Hits by IP" ; \
  awk '{ print $1 gsub(/^.*:\/\/|\"|\/.*$/,"",$11) "\t" $11 }' $1 | \
      sort | \
      uniq  -c | \
      sort -k3,3 -k1,1nr | \
      while n="" read a b c; do \
          [ $a = 1 ] && p='' || p=s ; \
          if [ "$n" = "$c" ] ; then \
               echo -n "  |  $a hit$p $b" ; \
          else echo ; \
               echo -n   "$c $a hit$p $b" ; \
          fi  ; n="$c" ; \
      done ; \
      echo ; \
} | \
while read a b ; do \
    printf "%-30s   %s\n" "$a" "$b" ; \
done
```

Output of `./ugly.sh accesslog`:

```
Domains                          Hits by IP

networkconfig.com                3 hits 51.254.56.62  |  2 hits 182.180.10.40
networkconfig.net                3 hits 51.254.56.62  |  2 hits 182.180.10.40
```

Output of `./ugly.sh log.txt`, (OP's URL for data: [log.txt](http://networkconfig.net/test/text.txt)):

```
Domains                          Hits by IP

-                                1 hit 180.76.15.138  |  1 hit 192.243.55.136
www.google.com.pk                3 hits 122.129.73.92
www.networkconfigorchard.com     2 hits 39.46.59.57  |  8 hits 39.46.6.0
```

Comment: thanks but it won't work with following file: http://networkconfig.net/test/logs.txt

Comment: Now fixed to work with '_logs.txt_'. also.

Comment: Please visit this link:  http://networkconfig.net/test/text.txt
Moreover could you send me script description how it works exactly.

Comment: That 'text.txt' must have started from some other log file, and the output has things that I'd hoped to have filtered out.  Perhaps a script file would do better: [ugly.sh](http://pastebin.com/XXBCJh4h), invoke it like this: `ugly.sh logs.txt` or whatever the file to test is.  If the results come out wrong, send a link to the tricky data for another fix.   (How it works: _awk_ rips out some fields, which are sorted in what should be the correct order, the _while_ loop puts the IP hits on the same line as the domain, the _sed_ removes unwanted frills, and _printf_ prints it neatly.)

Comment: Also, maybe the OP spec should be altered to include things like "-" for a Domain.

Comment: When i remove the path in ugly.sh than run it  like:  ugly.sh logs.txt
then it won't work.

Comment: That's normal, just run it with the path then.  Does it now work better, worse, or the same?

Comment: It works same as before.

Comment: Revised again, the trouble seems to have been that the URL cruft in $11 needed to be cleaned immediately, (rather than after all the looping), otherwise the `sort` would sort the gunk, and screw up the `uniq` count.